# Xcode 4: setting NSZombieEnabled environment variable for all projects?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Setting NSZombieEnabled = YES in the Environment variables is very useful to debug BAD MEMORY ACCESS issues.

However I need to set it for all projects. I was wondering if I can just set it in Xcode preferences. (xCode 4)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at following uris:

Setting environment variables for user processes: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1067/_index.html

Runtime Configuration Guide#Environment Variables: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html

Note: you need to logout/login to make it effective.

Comment: ok thanks. I guess you mean login/logout with OSX. One last question, in xcode plist editor I'm asked to set the type of the variable and I used "String", is that correct ? (In the original project environment variables there is not the type column).

Comment: Sorry not to mentioned that you need to logout/login from OSX:( And value must be string as document said :)